# how to access properties of view controller in UIView class

Tags: iphone

I have a `UIViewController` class that has a `NSString` and I want to fetch value of it in string of `UIView` that is subclass of  it but it is giving null ..
Here is my code

```
(viewController.m class)
 paintABC = [[BIDABCPaint alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,YOrigin, self.view.frame.size.width, newSize.height)];
  paintABC.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage];
    paintABC.BtnTag=TagName;

          [self.view addSubview:paintABC];

       [paintABC release];
```

When I am printing  btnTag it's giving null value.
I have already initialize TagName  of ViewController.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property `MyViewController *delegate` in the UIView subclass (BIDABCPaint subclass),synthesize it.In ViewController when you are adding this UIView add the following..

```
paintABC.delegate = self;
```

further whenever you need to access NSString of viewController..Apply

```
NSLog(@"%@",delegate.requiredString);
```

in the subClass ,but make sure to declare `requiredString` as a property of the viewController first,else accessing the string will not be possible because of class visibility constraints

Comment: I want to  access string of view controller in UIView.And i have done till PaintAbc.delegate=self                                            But delegate.requiredString is not clear for me .

Comment: requiredString is an example i mentioned.Required string is a pseudo name i used for string which u desire

Comment: I have done this    paintABC = [[BIDABCPaint alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,YOrigin, self.view.frame.size.width, newSize.height)];
    paintABC.delegate=self;
  paintABC.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage];
    paintABC.BtnTag=TagName;
     
          [self.view addSubview:paintABC];
here BtnTag is string of PaintAbc and TagNAme is of view controller but when i am printing BtnTag in  PaintAbc it is null . You Please elaborate it for me I am new in this

Comment: Have you synthesized tagName..i.e in .h file declare @property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *tagName;   and in .m file @synthesize tagName;